# gbXML example with SpaceBoundary

Tags: xml, gbxml

I'm developing an gbXML export and I want to understand how gbXML works with SpaceBoundary.
I understand gbXML with surfaces well, but with SpaceBoundary I have problems.

I'm searching for an example gbXML file with SpaceBoundary, but the [offical site](http://www.gbxml.org) nor the 1000 google search results I looked trought have an example.

Can some one help me please and upload an example?

Comment: You may want to ask this on https://unmethours.com/questions/